# is bottom to up method good for reading errors

Tags: cs50

iam new to programming and i have been taking cs50,so in lecture one prof.david said that "you should always start reading the errors displayed from top".So i don`t understand what that suppose to mean.can anyone tell me why did he said that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the propper method should be: first focus on last or biggest errors, isolate possible causes, test solutions independently and then integrate it all.

Also you should use SOLID principles to find and repair errors easier. Is a tough matter but is the best approach.